# Python composition

Tags: python, oop, composition

Just trying to improve my OO use in Python and am curious about composition.

Say for example you have the following classes:

```
Class Breakfast(object):
    __init__(self, eggs):
        self.eggs = eggs

    @property
    def yolk(self):
        return eggs.yolk

    @property
    def yolk_colour(self):
        return eggs.yolk.colour
        OR
        return.eggs.yolk_colour

Class Eggs(object):
    __init__(self, yolk):
        self.yolk = yolk

    @property
    def yolk_colour(self):
        return self.yolk.colour

Class Yolk(object):
    __init__(self, colour):
        self.colour = colour
```

And initialise them

```
eggs = Eggs(Yolk("yellow"))
bkfast = Breakfast(eggs)
```

When you want to access the yolk, is it better to chain it as in

```
bkfast.eggs.yolk
```

Or access it via a property

```
bkfast.yolk
```

The second version uses less chaining directly, although still does it behind the scenes. Whereas the first one shows you exactly what is going on. Is there a preferred method for this?

EDIT: I've put in a property of yolk that it has a colour. If you want to get that colour from the breakfast, is it better to have a property of breakfast that calls a property of eggs, or directly access the yolk itself? Or does it not matter as it's behind the scenes?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter - use the latter option

Comment: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/ The Zen of Python: Explicit is better than implicit. Simple is better than complex.

Comment: I would argue that you should use a getter method.

Comment: Can you please clarify the zen of Python here? To me "Explicit is better than implicit" favours the first approach as you're explicitly stating where the yolk comes from. "Simple is better than complex" on the other hand appears to support the second method.

Comment: @Stu: I would argue that "simple is better than complex" != "short is better than long". There is no tangible difference in complexity between calling something with a long name or a short name.

Comment: @MattWhipple I've added in another part to the question about getting the colour of the yolk. Does it matter how Breakfast returns the colour, or does it not matter as to the user it's still a single call and consistent with the Law of Demeter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The contrived classes in some way muddy the issue.  It somewhat depends on what you're trying to do, or specifically how the object graph that you're working with is defined.  The jump from `breakfast` to `yolk` is unnatural...you'd be unlikely to jump directly to the yolk child of the breakfast aggregate.

In this case the contract would likely be that the breakfast would deliver the `egg` object, so that is what you would return, and then get the yolk from there if needed (but then that only involves the `egg` object...`breakfast` stops caring.

If for some reason you did want to consistently grab the yolk, then you should use delegation.  You never want your client code to care about more than it has to or should (the Law of Demeter above), and you never want to have anything but the defined and managed API leak to the client code.

A more reasonable example would be supposing that you have eggs in different forms with breakfast, and so it may come from a plate, or a little soft boiled egg stand, or from a glass, "Rocky" style.  In that case the client code still just wants the egg, so you'd want to use delegation and fetch the egg out of the appropriate plate, stand, or glass child.

It comes down to defining what it is you are exposing to the client code, and make sure that any baggage or implementation details are handled and abstracted by the receiving object.  You always want to work in terms of what you are delivering and not where it is coming from.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Instead of the admittedly contrived breakfast example then, I have a class Container which acts as a container for a tree data structure (which has its own class Tree). That tree has a root_node. I want to hide the workings of the Tree from client code, and so the Container has utility methods to access it. That makes sense to me.

Comment: Does it matter how the Container accesses the root node? i.e. say the root node itself has a property 'value' and the client needs to know this. Container has a property 'root_value' to provide this functionality. Does it matter if this root_value property calls something like `self.tree.root_node.value`, or calls a property of tree which is also root_value, and thus returns `self.tree.root_value`?

Comment: This again depends on what you are designing.  The shortest answer is don't over-engineer so if you're not exposing the object outside of the present instance then you don't have to worry about it.  If you do have to worry about it...if `tree` is exposed elsewhere and you're traveling from implementation to API then the same principles above should be applied to it.  If that is case then I'd say you do need to also use sensible delegation there since judging from the sample call the client code shouldn't even care that it is a tree.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion for this particular example, It is better to access it via the property `bkfast.yolk`, because then you have the freedom of changing the underlying implementation of yolk.

Answer (score 0):

From [The Zen of Python](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)

```
Explicit is better than implicit.
Simple is better than complex.
```

To me it means your example doesn't have sense without a concrete problem. If you need to compose, do compose. If you don't need, don't. Think about the *meaning* of your interface, keep it *simple* and *explicit*.

What the yolk of a breakfast is about, anyway?